# How am I getting a form submission with empty data?

Tags: html, post, cgi, forms

This is more basic a position than I thought I'd asked in a while. I think I may have tripped over an HTML5 subtlety.

I have been working on building out the front end to a webapp, including a whole page submission via POST. If I submit a (light enough) combination of fields via GET, it appears in the URL and the CGI script sees a populated QUERY_STRING.

I am trying and failing to populate the QUERY_STRING via POST. The minimal example I have is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="test">
            <input type="submit">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

This results, as far as I can tell, is that the POST submission only ever submits an empty string. I have not had any particularly interesting difficulties with GET, but neither tweaking this example (e.g. lowercasing `POST`) nor tweaking the real code has let me successfully log a nonempty QUERY_STRING when submitted by POST.

What can/should I do so that I can pass XYZ values by POST to a CGI script and have QUERY_STRING be populated with the submitted data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST data is not appended to the QUERY_STRING, it is sent in the body of the request.

If you are processing the form submission yourself, without the benefit of a CGI library or framework, you will find your POST data on STDIN.

If you are using a library or framework, consult the documentation to see where the POST data has been stored.